# Can functions such as 'CONCAT' or 'DATANAME' be utilized in Alias in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a report that will forecast future gains. I am trying to find a way for my column names to update themselves over time from current month. My approach was to create the same case statement bellow for my future months by inclemently adding 1 to the month. However, it seems that I cannot use functions as ALIAS. What would you recommend I do?

```
CASE
  WHEN DATEDIFF(month, GETDATE(), j.Estimated_Start_Date) <= 0 AND 
       DATEDIFF(month, GETDATE(),j.Estimated_Comp_Date) >= 0 
  THEN 1
  ELSE 0
END AS **CONCAT(DATENAME(MONTH,j.Estimated_Start_Date),'-', DATENAME(YEAR,j.Estimated_Start_Date))**
```

Comment: An alias cannot be the result of a function call, unless you are using dynamic SQL.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Even if the case statement is right after a Select clause?

Comment: A column alias is just a name (i.e. identifier.) And of course it can't be changed from row to row...

Comment: But as you said it's for reporting purposes , then why don't just add it as a separate column what you want to use as an alias.

Comment: You'll need to use dynamic SQL to do this. Derived aliases (via a function or basic concatenation) are not allowed.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 I can do that, but then, the columns name are dates and i want to feed that query to a power BI dashboard without having to manually update the column name every months. i want the columns name to update automatically as we change months. Hence why i am looking for a way to name them with functions

Comment: I think that approach won't work, you can't change the name of a column without updating the Power BI dataset.

Comment: This sort of thing is usually done in Power BI itself using Pivot Columns.